# There's a shadow on my button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i'm creating a button programmaticly for an iPad application. when i see the button, there looks to be a shadow type thing below it. what is it and how can i get rid of it?

[image: shadow button]

here is the code that creates it:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:12];
[myButton setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.leftScrollView.frame.size.width, 50);

UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gear12.png"]];

[myButton addSubview:myImageView];
[self.leftScrollView addSubview:myButton];
```

UPDATE:

ok, i notice i only get that effect when its in my scrollview. if i add it to the view, no shadow effect.

the top test button, the button is a subview of the view. the bottom button is a subview of the scrollview which is a subview of the view (button/view vs button/scrollview/view).

white section is the view, grey is the scrollview/view.

[image: shadow effect 2]

UPDATE 2:

as pointed out by robmayor, UIButtons always have that double line effect, just not noticeble when the background color is white. the blue is a view and the grey is the subview scrollview.

[image]

Comment: this might be useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341319/how-to-get-rid-of-gap-around-round-rect-button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On iPads, a rounded-rect UIButton always draws a white line along its bottom edge.  You can't see that white line if the button's superview is white, but it's still there.

You have a few options:

- Make the superview white.  This is the easiest but you might not like the way it looks.
- Make some rounded rect images in your favorite image editor.  Set the button type to custom and set your rounded rect images as the button's images.
- Make a subclass of UIButton and override its `drawRect:` method.
- Set the button type to custom and use the button's layer properties (`button.layer.backgroundColor`, `button.layer.borderColor`, `button.layer.borderWidth`, `button.layer.cornerRadius`) to give the button a rounded rect appearance.  You'll have to update `button.layer.backgroundColor` when the button is touched if you want it to turn blue like a normal one does.  (Actually a normal one uses a blue gradient.)

Comment: this is rather silly of apple. makes adding a simple button more complex then it needs to be. thanks.

Comment: It seems that a rounded rect button is actually drawn as a single grouped-style UITableViewCell and thus inherits the white border at the bottom. This white border looks great for the bottom cell on a standard grouped-style table background. But making the button the same drawing code was a poor choice on Apple's part.

Answer (score 9):

This question is old (6 months) but i'have found a solution to delete/mask this bad effect of double lines.

```
[yourButton.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor]];
[yourButton.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[yourButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor]];
[yourButton.layer setShadowOpacity:0.1f];
[yourButton.layer setCornerRadius:10];
```

UIColor selected is depending of the current background of your view.

Result : [image]

Comment: This create a black border in button. Work better, but not remove the line.

Comment: This is perfect! (Although, I'm not sure setting the background color or shadow opacity is necessary.)

Answer (score -1):

Replace `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]` with:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton new];
```

or:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

You want to have your customized button. You can still make it with rounded corners if needed.

Comment: Why would that make a difference? Rounded rect buttons do not normally draw themselves twice like this. It is more likely that the OP is accidentally drawing two buttons in approximately the same place.

Comment: i'm only adding the single button in my code right now. i updated my question with added info. the second image, i just dragged buttons in the IB.

Comment: @matt, rounded rect buttons absolutely draw themselves like that.  It's trivial to check it for yourself in IB.

Comment: Ok... I agree now. Looks like the button is added twice. @rob mayoff: no they do not. I just checked :)

Comment: @robmayoff but why does it do that and how can i not have it draw that shadow effect thing?

Comment: Hey look, here's a view with its background color set to red, and **one** button as a subview: http://imgur.com/pbFtl  Notice how the button has a white line along the bottom?  That's how they draw themselves.  You can't see the button's white line when the superview's background is white, but the button always draws it.

Comment: The white line only shows up on iPad.  It doesn't show up on iPhone.

Comment: Did the same manually: [http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/screenshot20111129at927.png/](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/screenshot20111129at927.png/)

Comment: It turns out iPhone and iPad buttons give different results.

Comment: I do not see any lines in Simulator... (neither iPhone/iPad).