# How to get rid of gap around Round Rect Button without removing border around it?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

BTW. it may seem like duplicate of question about button shadow problem, but they have monotone background, in my case background is some image so simple border does not fix the problem.

While making app for iPhone/Pad I noticed that:
UIButton shows up with a white gap or line on the bottom if background is not white.


[image: button]

1. Any suggestions?
2. Cannot get rid of it?

[image]

PS. Jay Wardell's got it. Though I was not using image in the button, changing it to Custom type and rounding the corners did the trick. TY. Jay, post it as an answer I will mark it as correct one. The one that is on the left looks perfect now. Now I just have to change all my 100 or so buttons to Custom and round their corners, uhh thanks to XCode's misbehaving Round Rect Button.

[image]

Comment: iOS or MacOS? Please add the corresponding tag.

Comment: UIButton means iOS, right?

Comment: What's the type of the button?  If you're using a custom background image, it probably should be UIButtonTypeCustom. It looks like it may be UIButtonTypeRoundedRect instead.

Comment: dont know wth happend to the title it was saying that Round Rect Button, will edit that. And if i insert image into background it is fine, no gap shows up.

Comment: @BorisGafurov Are you using iPad?

Comment: @BorisGafurov My answer should help then...

Comment: is this button in UIWebView or pure UIButton? or show us the code you used for this button or some screen shots

Comment: it is simply added Rect Buttons on a view. image on top shows the button.

Comment: Jay Wardell's got it. Though I was not using image in the button, changing it to Custom type and rounding the corners did the trick. TY. Jay, post it as an answer I will mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It  looks like you had the button's type set to UIButtonTypeRoundedRect, which would mean that the button was drawing its round rect background THEN your custom background image.  Change the button's buttonType to UIButtonTypeCustom and it should work.